# Open URL and login

Tags: c#

I have been given as task for reconsiling online reports with excel reports, making sure that the data in the two always match. I am doing it manual right now and thinking of automating it using C#.

Reading the excel files should not be difficult.
However, for opening the online reports I have to open a URL, fill in the username and password, navigate to the report, fill-in the parameters for the report.
One report displayed as online SSRS report and the other is just a web page.

I want to know how can I automate this task, meaning how can I programatically login to the page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very generic and open ended question. I suggest starting with the [WebClient class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and using tools such as [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Monitor the web forms values with fiddler and build your requests. Pay attention to the headers and cookies.

Answer (score 0):

WatiN seems to be the one I was looking for !
Thanks ryan and also others who voted to close the thread for unknown reasons.